# accessing values inside a has_and_belongs_to_many via join_table

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database-schema

if i have the following relationship:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_and_belongs_to_many :members, join_table: :members_roles
end
```

and

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles, join_table: :members_roles
end
```

and i want to access the member_roles table - how can i do this? in my rails console:

```
m=Member.new
m.member_roles.new 

or 

r=Role.new
r.member_roles.new
```

doesn't work. Basically i want to set up a new relationship between a new model object and role object. how do i set this up?

if i try

```
m=Member_role.new
```

I get n name error:

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Member_Role
```

Even though inside my schema, there is a members_roles table:

```
create_table "members_roles", id: false, force: true do |t|
    t.integer "member_id"
    t.integer "role_id"
  end
```

I know there is something simple I am missing, but i am working with someone else's code and trying to figure it out - Ive never set up a many-to-many relationship in this way

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to access the model to create new association, but there is no extra data on the joint table, you can simply do:

```
m = Member.create
r = Role.create

m.roles << r
```

This will automatically create a new row in a joint table.

Note however, that if you have some extra data on the join table, you will not be able to use it with `habtm` association and `has_many :through` should be used instead